# Postgres Query to retrieve locations within a given distance

Tags: postgresql

I have the following sql query that works fine in MYSQL but it gives me an error in Postgres:

```
SELECT * , 
        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('13.1') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('53.1') ) + sin( radians('13.1') ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) AS distance 
FROM person 
HAVING distance < 10 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 20
```

```
**ERROR**:  column "distance" does not exist
LINE 1: ...(radians(lat)) ) ) AS distance FROM person HAVING distance <...
```

Comment: The distance between two points can be calculated a lot easier using [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) or the extension [earthdistance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/earthdistance.html)

Comment: You can't use an alias in a HAVING clause in PostgreSQL or SQL Server - MySQL does this as an "extension" to the standard. Are you using MySQL < 5.7.5? If `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is set, it won't work in MySQL either - see the links [here](https://www.google.com/search?ei=GugcXvmVOZSN1fAPuqy2iAw&q=alias+in+having+clause&oq=alias+in+having+&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0l2j0i22i30l8.14979.19292..20624...0.2..1.217.2339.35j1j2......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0i71j0i273j0i131j0i67j0i131i67j0i10.DZwWZqK68bc).

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat the expression in the filter condition, or you can avoid that by using a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, 
             3959 * acos(
                       cos(
                          radians('13.1')
                       ) * cos(
                          radians(lat)
                       ) * cos(
                          radians(lng) - radians('53.1')
                       ) + sin(
                          radians('13.1')
                       ) * sin(radians(lat))
                    ) AS distance 
      FROM person) AS q 
WHERE distance < 10 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a_horse_with_no_name's comment to a coded answer, simply repace your `HAVING` keyword with `WHERE`:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT 
            *, 
            ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('13.1') ) 
            * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) 
            - radians('53.1') ) + sin( radians('13.1') ) 
            * sin(radians(lat)) ) 
            ) AS distance 
    FROM person) t
WHERE distance < 10 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 20
```

Comment: You can't use a column alias in the WHERE clause

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - can you use CTEs in postgresql? If so, I'll re-write that way. If not, then you could reproduce the column definition in the where clause. I hate that, but not every DBMS supports referencing aliases in the `WHERE` clause, unfortunately :/

Comment: yes, of course you can use CTEs, but that's not necessary for this. A simple derived table will do just fine. `select * from ( select .., as distance) t where distance < 10 ...`

Comment: The reason why Postgres (and other DBMS) don't support to use an alias in the WHERE clause is that this isn't defined in the SQL standard

Comment: Cheers. Have adjusted.

Comment: Perfect, simple answer! I'll also try: "using PostGIS" thank you @earthdistance – a_horse_with_no_name